# OpenLayers how to calculate LineString distance?

Tags: javascript, gps, openlayers-6

using OpenLayers 6.5.0 and OpenStreetMap. How can I calculate route distance? I created LineString based on coordinates. In next steps I use `ol.sphere.getLength()` and `lineString.getLength()` but I'm getting strange results.

I tried to convert coordinates to .gpx file and import it to online gpx distance calculator and the result was about 4,39 km.

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/re02Lnx7/2/

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  [15.94606, 51.57557],
  [15.94602, 51.57572],
  [15.94604, 51.57576],
  [15.946, 51.57581],
  [15.94588, 51.57586],
  [15.94567, 51.57591],
  [15.94543, 51.57597],
  [15.94527, 51.57602],
  [15.94513, 51.57605],
  [15.94502, 51.57607],
  [15.94497, 51.57609],
  [15.94499, 51.57609],
  [15.94497, 51.57611],
  [15.94501, 51.57616],
  [15.94525, 51.57636],
  [15.94538, 51.57648],
  [15.94548, 51.57662],
  [15.94558, 51.57675],
  [15.94568, 51.57688],
  [15.94578, 51.57702],
  [15.94589, 51.57712],
  [15.94597, 51.57724],
  [15.94604, 51.57735],
  [15.94611, 51.57743],
  [15.94614, 51.57748],
  [15.94615, 51.57752],
  [15.94618, 51.5776],
  [15.94621, 51.57771],
  [15.94627, 51.57784],
  [15.94636, 51.57796],
  [15.94645, 51.57809],
  [15.94653, 51.57825],
  [15.94661, 51.57839],
  [15.9467, 51.57852],
  [15.94679, 51.57865],
  [15.94687, 51.57878],
  [15.94695, 51.5789],
  [15.94703, 51.579],
  [15.94707, 51.57907],
  [15.9471, 51.57912],
  [15.94713, 51.57916],
  [15.94718, 51.57923],
  [15.94725, 51.57933],
  [15.94732, 51.57945],
  [15.9474, 51.57957],
  [15.94747, 51.57969],
  [15.94754, 51.57981],
  [15.94763, 51.57994],
  [15.9477, 51.58006],
  [15.94776, 51.58014],
  [15.94783, 51.58016],
  [15.94796, 51.58012],
  [15.94812, 51.58001],
  [15.94828, 51.57991],
  [15.9484, 51.57983],
  [15.94852, 51.57973],
  [15.94863, 51.57964],
  [15.9487, 51.57955],
  [15.9488, 51.57948],
  [15.94891, 51.57942],
  [15.94907, 51.57939],
  [15.94923, 51.57935],
  [15.9494, 51.57931],
  [15.94955, 51.57925],
  [15.94967, 51.57921],
  [15.94971, 51.57919],
  [15.94973, 51.57916],
  [15.94966, 51.5791],
  [15.94956, 51.57898],
  [15.94942, 51.57884],
  [15.9493, 51.5787],
  [15.9492, 51.57857],
  [15.94912, 51.57841],
  [15.94904, 51.57825],
  [15.94894, 51.5781],
  [15.94884, 51.57796],
  [15.94875, 51.57781],
  [15.94864, 51.57767],
  [15.94853, 51.57754],
  [15.94843, 51.57742],
  [15.94834, 51.57728],
  [15.94826, 51.57714],
  [15.94817, 51.57701],
  [15.94807, 51.57689],
  [15.94801, 51.57681],
  [15.94803, 51.57679],
  [15.94804, 51.57678],
  [15.94812, 51.57671],
  [15.94827, 51.57666],
  [15.94849, 51.57658],
  [15.94876, 51.57648],
  [15.94904, 51.57637],
  [15.9493, 51.57626],
  [15.94956, 51.57617],
  [15.94988, 51.57604],
  [15.95012, 51.57595],
  [15.95026, 51.57589],
  [15.95033, 51.57586],
  [15.95039, 51.57583],
  [15.9505, 51.5758],
  [15.95064, 51.57574],
  [15.95076, 51.5757],
  [15.95079, 51.57569],
  [15.95079, 51.5757],
  [15.9508, 51.57567],
  [15.95073, 51.57558],
  [15.95059, 51.57546],
  [15.95042, 51.57529],
  [15.95025, 51.57511],
  [15.95007, 51.57492],
  [15.94989, 51.57473],
  [15.94969, 51.57453],
  [15.9495, 51.57434],
  [15.94932, 51.57416],
  [15.94915, 51.574],
  [15.94893, 51.57391],
  [15.94879, 51.57375],
  [15.94867, 51.5736],
  [15.94858, 51.57352],
  [15.94847, 51.57349],
  [15.94835, 51.57344],
  [15.9482, 51.57336],
  [15.94806, 51.57326],
  [15.94795, 51.57314],
  [15.94789, 51.57301],
  [15.94788, 51.57288],
  [15.94787, 51.57273],
  [15.94785, 51.57259],
  [15.94784, 51.57245],
  [15.94783, 51.5723],
  [15.94782, 51.57216],
  [15.94781, 51.57204],
  [15.94776, 51.57193],
  [15.9476, 51.57186],
  [15.94738, 51.57182],
  [15.9471, 51.57178],
  [15.9468, 51.57177],
  [15.94651, 51.57174],
  [15.94619, 51.57172],
  [15.94588, 51.5717],
  [15.94558, 51.57169],
  [15.94526, 51.5717],
  [15.94492, 51.57172],
  [15.94457, 51.57173],
  [15.94422, 51.57174],
  [15.94388, 51.57173],
  [15.94353, 51.57169],
  [15.94318, 51.57164],
  [15.94285, 51.5716],
  [15.94253, 51.57156],
  [15.9422, 51.57152],
  [15.94188, 51.57148],
  [15.9416, 51.57146],
  [15.94134, 51.57146],
  [15.94108, 51.5715],
  [15.94084, 51.57158],
  [15.94064, 51.5717],
  [15.94045, 51.57183],
  [15.9402, 51.57193],
  [15.93992, 51.572],
  [15.93962, 51.57208],
  [15.93931, 51.57216],
  [15.93901, 51.57224],
  [15.9387, 51.57232],
  [15.93839, 51.5724],
  [15.93808, 51.57248],
  [15.93779, 51.57255],
  [15.93749, 51.57263],
  [15.93719, 51.57272],
  [15.93695, 51.5728],
  [15.9367, 51.57288],
  [15.93646, 51.57296],
  [15.9363, 51.57301],
  [15.93625, 51.57305],
  [15.93628, 51.57317],
  [15.93631, 51.57332],
  [15.93634, 51.57346],
  [15.93642, 51.57359],
  [15.93651, 51.57372],
  [15.93657, 51.57389],
  [15.93654, 51.57407],
  [15.93646, 51.57425],
  [15.93639, 51.57445],
  [15.93636, 51.57464],
  [15.93635, 51.57481],
  [15.93636, 51.57497],
  [15.9364, 51.57514],
  [15.93646, 51.57531],
  [15.93651, 51.57548],
  [15.93656, 51.57565],
  [15.93661, 51.57581],
  [15.93667, 51.57598],
  [15.93671, 51.57614],
  [15.93677, 51.57631],
  [15.93684, 51.57649],
  [15.93691, 51.57666],
  [15.93697, 51.57682],
  [15.93705, 51.57699],
  [15.93715, 51.57714],
  [15.93725, 51.57731],
  [15.93735, 51.57747],
  [15.93746, 51.57764],
  [15.93756, 51.57781],
  [15.93767, 51.57798],
  [15.93776, 51.57814],
  [15.93786, 51.57829],
  [15.93797, 51.57844],
  [15.93807, 51.57859],
  [15.93819, 51.57874],
  [15.9383, 51.57887],
  [15.93839, 51.57898],
  [15.93845, 51.57904],
  [15.93849, 51.57906],
  [15.93855, 51.57907],
  [15.93866, 51.57904],
  [15.9388, 51.57901],
  [15.93895, 51.579],
  [15.93907, 51.57909],
  [15.93921, 51.57923],
  [15.93933, 51.57939],
  [15.93943, 51.57953],
  [15.93953, 51.57966],
  [15.93961, 51.57977],
  [15.93968, 51.57985],
  [15.93977, 51.57988],
  [15.93992, 51.57981],
  [15.94014, 51.57972],
  [15.94037, 51.57963],
  [15.94061, 51.57953],
  [15.94084, 51.57944],
  [15.94099, 51.57939],
  [15.94105, 51.57936],
  [15.9411, 51.57933],
  [15.94123, 51.57927],
  [15.94147, 51.57919],
  [15.94179, 51.57909],
  [15.9421, 51.57898],
  [15.94238, 51.57888],
  [15.94266, 51.57878],
  [15.94295, 51.57868],
  [15.94323, 51.57858],
  [15.94349, 51.57848],
  [15.94373, 51.57838],
  [15.94399, 51.57827],
  [15.94424, 51.57819],
  [15.94451, 51.57809],
  [15.94478, 51.578],
  [15.94504, 51.57791],
  [15.9453, 51.57782],
  [15.94555, 51.57773],
  [15.94579, 51.57764],
  [15.946, 51.57756],
  [15.94622, 51.57747],
  [15.94645, 51.57739],
  [15.94669, 51.5773],
  [15.94693, 51.57722],
  [15.94717, 51.57713],
  [15.9474, 51.57705],
  [15.94759, 51.57697],
  [15.94778, 51.57689],
  [15.94799, 51.57681],
  [15.94814, 51.57676],
  [15.9482, 51.5767],
  [15.94814, 51.57662],
  [15.94805, 51.57652],
  [15.94795, 51.57641],
  [15.94786, 51.57629],
  [15.94777, 51.57618],
  [15.94765, 51.57607],
  [15.9475, 51.57598],
  [15.94732, 51.57592],
  [15.94711, 51.57588],
  [15.9469, 51.57584],
  [15.94671, 51.57579],
  [15.94653, 51.57574],
  [15.94636, 51.57568],
  [15.94617, 51.57566],
  [15.94605, 51.57565],
  [15.94602, 51.57566],
  [15.94603, 51.57566],
  [15.94603, 51.57567],
  [15.94604, 51.57567],
  [15.94605, 51.57567],
  [15.94608, 51.57567],
  [15.94612, 51.57567],
  [15.94613, 51.57566],
  [15.94614, 51.57566]
];

var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString(locations)


var lineLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [new ol.Feature({
      geometry: lineString,
      name: 'Line'
    })]
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'red',
      opacity: 0.5,
      width: 5
    })
  })
});

var view = new ol.View({
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  center: [15.94616, 51.57555],
  zoom: 13
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    lineLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: view
});

console.log(ol.sphere.getLength(lineString));
console.log(lineString.getLength());
```

```css
body,
html,
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js "></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css">
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your projection is not the default EPSG:3857 you must specify projection in `ol.sphere.getLength()`

```js
var locations = [
  [15.94606, 51.57557],
  [15.94602, 51.57572],
  [15.94604, 51.57576],
  [15.946, 51.57581],
  [15.94588, 51.57586],
  [15.94567, 51.57591],
  [15.94543, 51.57597],
  [15.94527, 51.57602],
  [15.94513, 51.57605],
  [15.94502, 51.57607],
  [15.94497, 51.57609],
  [15.94499, 51.57609],
  [15.94497, 51.57611],
  [15.94501, 51.57616],
  [15.94525, 51.57636],
  [15.94538, 51.57648],
  [15.94548, 51.57662],
  [15.94558, 51.57675],
  [15.94568, 51.57688],
  [15.94578, 51.57702],
  [15.94589, 51.57712],
  [15.94597, 51.57724],
  [15.94604, 51.57735],
  [15.94611, 51.57743],
  [15.94614, 51.57748],
  [15.94615, 51.57752],
  [15.94618, 51.5776],
  [15.94621, 51.57771],
  [15.94627, 51.57784],
  [15.94636, 51.57796],
  [15.94645, 51.57809],
  [15.94653, 51.57825],
  [15.94661, 51.57839],
  [15.9467, 51.57852],
  [15.94679, 51.57865],
  [15.94687, 51.57878],
  [15.94695, 51.5789],
  [15.94703, 51.579],
  [15.94707, 51.57907],
  [15.9471, 51.57912],
  [15.94713, 51.57916],
  [15.94718, 51.57923],
  [15.94725, 51.57933],
  [15.94732, 51.57945],
  [15.9474, 51.57957],
  [15.94747, 51.57969],
  [15.94754, 51.57981],
  [15.94763, 51.57994],
  [15.9477, 51.58006],
  [15.94776, 51.58014],
  [15.94783, 51.58016],
  [15.94796, 51.58012],
  [15.94812, 51.58001],
  [15.94828, 51.57991],
  [15.9484, 51.57983],
  [15.94852, 51.57973],
  [15.94863, 51.57964],
  [15.9487, 51.57955],
  [15.9488, 51.57948],
  [15.94891, 51.57942],
  [15.94907, 51.57939],
  [15.94923, 51.57935],
  [15.9494, 51.57931],
  [15.94955, 51.57925],
  [15.94967, 51.57921],
  [15.94971, 51.57919],
  [15.94973, 51.57916],
  [15.94966, 51.5791],
  [15.94956, 51.57898],
  [15.94942, 51.57884],
  [15.9493, 51.5787],
  [15.9492, 51.57857],
  [15.94912, 51.57841],
  [15.94904, 51.57825],
  [15.94894, 51.5781],
  [15.94884, 51.57796],
  [15.94875, 51.57781],
  [15.94864, 51.57767],
  [15.94853, 51.57754],
  [15.94843, 51.57742],
  [15.94834, 51.57728],
  [15.94826, 51.57714],
  [15.94817, 51.57701],
  [15.94807, 51.57689],
  [15.94801, 51.57681],
  [15.94803, 51.57679],
  [15.94804, 51.57678],
  [15.94812, 51.57671],
  [15.94827, 51.57666],
  [15.94849, 51.57658],
  [15.94876, 51.57648],
  [15.94904, 51.57637],
  [15.9493, 51.57626],
  [15.94956, 51.57617],
  [15.94988, 51.57604],
  [15.95012, 51.57595],
  [15.95026, 51.57589],
  [15.95033, 51.57586],
  [15.95039, 51.57583],
  [15.9505, 51.5758],
  [15.95064, 51.57574],
  [15.95076, 51.5757],
  [15.95079, 51.57569],
  [15.95079, 51.5757],
  [15.9508, 51.57567],
  [15.95073, 51.57558],
  [15.95059, 51.57546],
  [15.95042, 51.57529],
  [15.95025, 51.57511],
  [15.95007, 51.57492],
  [15.94989, 51.57473],
  [15.94969, 51.57453],
  [15.9495, 51.57434],
  [15.94932, 51.57416],
  [15.94915, 51.574],
  [15.94893, 51.57391],
  [15.94879, 51.57375],
  [15.94867, 51.5736],
  [15.94858, 51.57352],
  [15.94847, 51.57349],
  [15.94835, 51.57344],
  [15.9482, 51.57336],
  [15.94806, 51.57326],
  [15.94795, 51.57314],
  [15.94789, 51.57301],
  [15.94788, 51.57288],
  [15.94787, 51.57273],
  [15.94785, 51.57259],
  [15.94784, 51.57245],
  [15.94783, 51.5723],
  [15.94782, 51.57216],
  [15.94781, 51.57204],
  [15.94776, 51.57193],
  [15.9476, 51.57186],
  [15.94738, 51.57182],
  [15.9471, 51.57178],
  [15.9468, 51.57177],
  [15.94651, 51.57174],
  [15.94619, 51.57172],
  [15.94588, 51.5717],
  [15.94558, 51.57169],
  [15.94526, 51.5717],
  [15.94492, 51.57172],
  [15.94457, 51.57173],
  [15.94422, 51.57174],
  [15.94388, 51.57173],
  [15.94353, 51.57169],
  [15.94318, 51.57164],
  [15.94285, 51.5716],
  [15.94253, 51.57156],
  [15.9422, 51.57152],
  [15.94188, 51.57148],
  [15.9416, 51.57146],
  [15.94134, 51.57146],
  [15.94108, 51.5715],
  [15.94084, 51.57158],
  [15.94064, 51.5717],
  [15.94045, 51.57183],
  [15.9402, 51.57193],
  [15.93992, 51.572],
  [15.93962, 51.57208],
  [15.93931, 51.57216],
  [15.93901, 51.57224],
  [15.9387, 51.57232],
  [15.93839, 51.5724],
  [15.93808, 51.57248],
  [15.93779, 51.57255],
  [15.93749, 51.57263],
  [15.93719, 51.57272],
  [15.93695, 51.5728],
  [15.9367, 51.57288],
  [15.93646, 51.57296],
  [15.9363, 51.57301],
  [15.93625, 51.57305],
  [15.93628, 51.57317],
  [15.93631, 51.57332],
  [15.93634, 51.57346],
  [15.93642, 51.57359],
  [15.93651, 51.57372],
  [15.93657, 51.57389],
  [15.93654, 51.57407],
  [15.93646, 51.57425],
  [15.93639, 51.57445],
  [15.93636, 51.57464],
  [15.93635, 51.57481],
  [15.93636, 51.57497],
  [15.9364, 51.57514],
  [15.93646, 51.57531],
  [15.93651, 51.57548],
  [15.93656, 51.57565],
  [15.93661, 51.57581],
  [15.93667, 51.57598],
  [15.93671, 51.57614],
  [15.93677, 51.57631],
  [15.93684, 51.57649],
  [15.93691, 51.57666],
  [15.93697, 51.57682],
  [15.93705, 51.57699],
  [15.93715, 51.57714],
  [15.93725, 51.57731],
  [15.93735, 51.57747],
  [15.93746, 51.57764],
  [15.93756, 51.57781],
  [15.93767, 51.57798],
  [15.93776, 51.57814],
  [15.93786, 51.57829],
  [15.93797, 51.57844],
  [15.93807, 51.57859],
  [15.93819, 51.57874],
  [15.9383, 51.57887],
  [15.93839, 51.57898],
  [15.93845, 51.57904],
  [15.93849, 51.57906],
  [15.93855, 51.57907],
  [15.93866, 51.57904],
  [15.9388, 51.57901],
  [15.93895, 51.579],
  [15.93907, 51.57909],
  [15.93921, 51.57923],
  [15.93933, 51.57939],
  [15.93943, 51.57953],
  [15.93953, 51.57966],
  [15.93961, 51.57977],
  [15.93968, 51.57985],
  [15.93977, 51.57988],
  [15.93992, 51.57981],
  [15.94014, 51.57972],
  [15.94037, 51.57963],
  [15.94061, 51.57953],
  [15.94084, 51.57944],
  [15.94099, 51.57939],
  [15.94105, 51.57936],
  [15.9411, 51.57933],
  [15.94123, 51.57927],
  [15.94147, 51.57919],
  [15.94179, 51.57909],
  [15.9421, 51.57898],
  [15.94238, 51.57888],
  [15.94266, 51.57878],
  [15.94295, 51.57868],
  [15.94323, 51.57858],
  [15.94349, 51.57848],
  [15.94373, 51.57838],
  [15.94399, 51.57827],
  [15.94424, 51.57819],
  [15.94451, 51.57809],
  [15.94478, 51.578],
  [15.94504, 51.57791],
  [15.9453, 51.57782],
  [15.94555, 51.57773],
  [15.94579, 51.57764],
  [15.946, 51.57756],
  [15.94622, 51.57747],
  [15.94645, 51.57739],
  [15.94669, 51.5773],
  [15.94693, 51.57722],
  [15.94717, 51.57713],
  [15.9474, 51.57705],
  [15.94759, 51.57697],
  [15.94778, 51.57689],
  [15.94799, 51.57681],
  [15.94814, 51.57676],
  [15.9482, 51.5767],
  [15.94814, 51.57662],
  [15.94805, 51.57652],
  [15.94795, 51.57641],
  [15.94786, 51.57629],
  [15.94777, 51.57618],
  [15.94765, 51.57607],
  [15.9475, 51.57598],
  [15.94732, 51.57592],
  [15.94711, 51.57588],
  [15.9469, 51.57584],
  [15.94671, 51.57579],
  [15.94653, 51.57574],
  [15.94636, 51.57568],
  [15.94617, 51.57566],
  [15.94605, 51.57565],
  [15.94602, 51.57566],
  [15.94603, 51.57566],
  [15.94603, 51.57567],
  [15.94604, 51.57567],
  [15.94605, 51.57567],
  [15.94608, 51.57567],
  [15.94612, 51.57567],
  [15.94613, 51.57566],
  [15.94614, 51.57566]
];

var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString(locations)


var lineLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [new ol.Feature({
      geometry: lineString,
      name: 'Line'
    })]
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'red',
      opacity: 0.5,
      width: 5
    })
  })
});

var view = new ol.View({
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  center: [15.94616, 51.57555],
  zoom: 13
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    lineLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: view
});

console.log(ol.sphere.getLength(lineString, {projection: 'EPSG:4326'}));
console.log(lineString.getLength());
```

```css
body,
html,
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js "></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css">
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

It would be better to use an EPSG:3857 view to match the OSM base map

```js
var locations = [
  [15.94606, 51.57557],
  [15.94602, 51.57572],
  [15.94604, 51.57576],
  [15.946, 51.57581],
  [15.94588, 51.57586],
  [15.94567, 51.57591],
  [15.94543, 51.57597],
  [15.94527, 51.57602],
  [15.94513, 51.57605],
  [15.94502, 51.57607],
  [15.94497, 51.57609],
  [15.94499, 51.57609],
  [15.94497, 51.57611],
  [15.94501, 51.57616],
  [15.94525, 51.57636],
  [15.94538, 51.57648],
  [15.94548, 51.57662],
  [15.94558, 51.57675],
  [15.94568, 51.57688],
  [15.94578, 51.57702],
  [15.94589, 51.57712],
  [15.94597, 51.57724],
  [15.94604, 51.57735],
  [15.94611, 51.57743],
  [15.94614, 51.57748],
  [15.94615, 51.57752],
  [15.94618, 51.5776],
  [15.94621, 51.57771],
  [15.94627, 51.57784],
  [15.94636, 51.57796],
  [15.94645, 51.57809],
  [15.94653, 51.57825],
  [15.94661, 51.57839],
  [15.9467, 51.57852],
  [15.94679, 51.57865],
  [15.94687, 51.57878],
  [15.94695, 51.5789],
  [15.94703, 51.579],
  [15.94707, 51.57907],
  [15.9471, 51.57912],
  [15.94713, 51.57916],
  [15.94718, 51.57923],
  [15.94725, 51.57933],
  [15.94732, 51.57945],
  [15.9474, 51.57957],
  [15.94747, 51.57969],
  [15.94754, 51.57981],
  [15.94763, 51.57994],
  [15.9477, 51.58006],
  [15.94776, 51.58014],
  [15.94783, 51.58016],
  [15.94796, 51.58012],
  [15.94812, 51.58001],
  [15.94828, 51.57991],
  [15.9484, 51.57983],
  [15.94852, 51.57973],
  [15.94863, 51.57964],
  [15.9487, 51.57955],
  [15.9488, 51.57948],
  [15.94891, 51.57942],
  [15.94907, 51.57939],
  [15.94923, 51.57935],
  [15.9494, 51.57931],
  [15.94955, 51.57925],
  [15.94967, 51.57921],
  [15.94971, 51.57919],
  [15.94973, 51.57916],
  [15.94966, 51.5791],
  [15.94956, 51.57898],
  [15.94942, 51.57884],
  [15.9493, 51.5787],
  [15.9492, 51.57857],
  [15.94912, 51.57841],
  [15.94904, 51.57825],
  [15.94894, 51.5781],
  [15.94884, 51.57796],
  [15.94875, 51.57781],
  [15.94864, 51.57767],
  [15.94853, 51.57754],
  [15.94843, 51.57742],
  [15.94834, 51.57728],
  [15.94826, 51.57714],
  [15.94817, 51.57701],
  [15.94807, 51.57689],
  [15.94801, 51.57681],
  [15.94803, 51.57679],
  [15.94804, 51.57678],
  [15.94812, 51.57671],
  [15.94827, 51.57666],
  [15.94849, 51.57658],
  [15.94876, 51.57648],
  [15.94904, 51.57637],
  [15.9493, 51.57626],
  [15.94956, 51.57617],
  [15.94988, 51.57604],
  [15.95012, 51.57595],
  [15.95026, 51.57589],
  [15.95033, 51.57586],
  [15.95039, 51.57583],
  [15.9505, 51.5758],
  [15.95064, 51.57574],
  [15.95076, 51.5757],
  [15.95079, 51.57569],
  [15.95079, 51.5757],
  [15.9508, 51.57567],
  [15.95073, 51.57558],
  [15.95059, 51.57546],
  [15.95042, 51.57529],
  [15.95025, 51.57511],
  [15.95007, 51.57492],
  [15.94989, 51.57473],
  [15.94969, 51.57453],
  [15.9495, 51.57434],
  [15.94932, 51.57416],
  [15.94915, 51.574],
  [15.94893, 51.57391],
  [15.94879, 51.57375],
  [15.94867, 51.5736],
  [15.94858, 51.57352],
  [15.94847, 51.57349],
  [15.94835, 51.57344],
  [15.9482, 51.57336],
  [15.94806, 51.57326],
  [15.94795, 51.57314],
  [15.94789, 51.57301],
  [15.94788, 51.57288],
  [15.94787, 51.57273],
  [15.94785, 51.57259],
  [15.94784, 51.57245],
  [15.94783, 51.5723],
  [15.94782, 51.57216],
  [15.94781, 51.57204],
  [15.94776, 51.57193],
  [15.9476, 51.57186],
  [15.94738, 51.57182],
  [15.9471, 51.57178],
  [15.9468, 51.57177],
  [15.94651, 51.57174],
  [15.94619, 51.57172],
  [15.94588, 51.5717],
  [15.94558, 51.57169],
  [15.94526, 51.5717],
  [15.94492, 51.57172],
  [15.94457, 51.57173],
  [15.94422, 51.57174],
  [15.94388, 51.57173],
  [15.94353, 51.57169],
  [15.94318, 51.57164],
  [15.94285, 51.5716],
  [15.94253, 51.57156],
  [15.9422, 51.57152],
  [15.94188, 51.57148],
  [15.9416, 51.57146],
  [15.94134, 51.57146],
  [15.94108, 51.5715],
  [15.94084, 51.57158],
  [15.94064, 51.5717],
  [15.94045, 51.57183],
  [15.9402, 51.57193],
  [15.93992, 51.572],
  [15.93962, 51.57208],
  [15.93931, 51.57216],
  [15.93901, 51.57224],
  [15.9387, 51.57232],
  [15.93839, 51.5724],
  [15.93808, 51.57248],
  [15.93779, 51.57255],
  [15.93749, 51.57263],
  [15.93719, 51.57272],
  [15.93695, 51.5728],
  [15.9367, 51.57288],
  [15.93646, 51.57296],
  [15.9363, 51.57301],
  [15.93625, 51.57305],
  [15.93628, 51.57317],
  [15.93631, 51.57332],
  [15.93634, 51.57346],
  [15.93642, 51.57359],
  [15.93651, 51.57372],
  [15.93657, 51.57389],
  [15.93654, 51.57407],
  [15.93646, 51.57425],
  [15.93639, 51.57445],
  [15.93636, 51.57464],
  [15.93635, 51.57481],
  [15.93636, 51.57497],
  [15.9364, 51.57514],
  [15.93646, 51.57531],
  [15.93651, 51.57548],
  [15.93656, 51.57565],
  [15.93661, 51.57581],
  [15.93667, 51.57598],
  [15.93671, 51.57614],
  [15.93677, 51.57631],
  [15.93684, 51.57649],
  [15.93691, 51.57666],
  [15.93697, 51.57682],
  [15.93705, 51.57699],
  [15.93715, 51.57714],
  [15.93725, 51.57731],
  [15.93735, 51.57747],
  [15.93746, 51.57764],
  [15.93756, 51.57781],
  [15.93767, 51.57798],
  [15.93776, 51.57814],
  [15.93786, 51.57829],
  [15.93797, 51.57844],
  [15.93807, 51.57859],
  [15.93819, 51.57874],
  [15.9383, 51.57887],
  [15.93839, 51.57898],
  [15.93845, 51.57904],
  [15.93849, 51.57906],
  [15.93855, 51.57907],
  [15.93866, 51.57904],
  [15.9388, 51.57901],
  [15.93895, 51.579],
  [15.93907, 51.57909],
  [15.93921, 51.57923],
  [15.93933, 51.57939],
  [15.93943, 51.57953],
  [15.93953, 51.57966],
  [15.93961, 51.57977],
  [15.93968, 51.57985],
  [15.93977, 51.57988],
  [15.93992, 51.57981],
  [15.94014, 51.57972],
  [15.94037, 51.57963],
  [15.94061, 51.57953],
  [15.94084, 51.57944],
  [15.94099, 51.57939],
  [15.94105, 51.57936],
  [15.9411, 51.57933],
  [15.94123, 51.57927],
  [15.94147, 51.57919],
  [15.94179, 51.57909],
  [15.9421, 51.57898],
  [15.94238, 51.57888],
  [15.94266, 51.57878],
  [15.94295, 51.57868],
  [15.94323, 51.57858],
  [15.94349, 51.57848],
  [15.94373, 51.57838],
  [15.94399, 51.57827],
  [15.94424, 51.57819],
  [15.94451, 51.57809],
  [15.94478, 51.578],
  [15.94504, 51.57791],
  [15.9453, 51.57782],
  [15.94555, 51.57773],
  [15.94579, 51.57764],
  [15.946, 51.57756],
  [15.94622, 51.57747],
  [15.94645, 51.57739],
  [15.94669, 51.5773],
  [15.94693, 51.57722],
  [15.94717, 51.57713],
  [15.9474, 51.57705],
  [15.94759, 51.57697],
  [15.94778, 51.57689],
  [15.94799, 51.57681],
  [15.94814, 51.57676],
  [15.9482, 51.5767],
  [15.94814, 51.57662],
  [15.94805, 51.57652],
  [15.94795, 51.57641],
  [15.94786, 51.57629],
  [15.94777, 51.57618],
  [15.94765, 51.57607],
  [15.9475, 51.57598],
  [15.94732, 51.57592],
  [15.94711, 51.57588],
  [15.9469, 51.57584],
  [15.94671, 51.57579],
  [15.94653, 51.57574],
  [15.94636, 51.57568],
  [15.94617, 51.57566],
  [15.94605, 51.57565],
  [15.94602, 51.57566],
  [15.94603, 51.57566],
  [15.94603, 51.57567],
  [15.94604, 51.57567],
  [15.94605, 51.57567],
  [15.94608, 51.57567],
  [15.94612, 51.57567],
  [15.94613, 51.57566],
  [15.94614, 51.57566]
];

var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString(locations).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')


var lineLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [new ol.Feature({
      geometry: lineString,
      name: 'Line'
    })]
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'red',
      opacity: 0.5,
      width: 5
    })
  })
});

var view = new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([15.94616, 51.57555]),
  zoom: 13
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    lineLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: view
});

console.log(ol.sphere.getLength(lineString));
console.log(lineString.getLength());
```

```css
body,
html,
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js "></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css">
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```